# Can you have more spells known of a certain spell level than you have spell slots of that level?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, spell-slots

For instance, the sorcerer's [Spellcasting](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/sorcerer#Spellcasting) feature (PHB p. 101) says:

> #### Spells Known of 1st Level and Higher
>
> [...] The Spells Known column of the Sorcerer table shows when you learn more sorcerer spells of your choice. Each of these spells must be of a level of which you have spell slots. [...]
>
> Additionally, when you gain a level in this class, you can choose one of the sorcerer spells you know and replace it with another spell from the sorcerer spell list, which also must be of a level for which you have spell slots.

Can I both learn a 4th-level spell and replace a 1st-level spell with another 4th-level spell, even if I only have one 4th-level spell slot as a 7th-level sorcerer?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Be sure to take the [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour)! Try to make your title short and punchy, and give more detail in the body (don't be afraid to restate your question in a more detailed sense).

Comment: You should also make sure to type out all the features mentioned as well as link to the dndbeyond source or reference the page of the relevant book. I've gone ahead and done this so you get an idea of what questions should look like. Happy asking!

Answer (score 9):

## Yes

You can do this. An example of this would be learning *blight* when you turn 7th level, and at the same time unlearning *burning hands* and learning *dimension door*.

The reason for this is the phrase:

> which must be for a level for which you have spell slots.

Because you are a level 7 sorcerer, you have 4th level spell slots, and so in the separate instances of 1) learning a spell, and 2) replacing a spell, you can do that for a spell which is a level for which you have spell slots.

Also, it is important to keep "spells known" and "spell slots" distinct, because spell slots are the given power you have (often described as mana or energy in other games and systems) and spells known are the versatility you have. Having 2 4th level spells at your disposal can be useful, even if you only have 1 4th level spell slot, because the situations you use *dimension door* and *blight* in are very different.